# Regular expression to find usage of + operator for String concatination

Tags: regex

Is there any regex which can give me usage of `+` operator for String concatenation.

Right now I am using

```
return (( textLine =~ /\".*\s*\"\s*\+/)||(textLine=~ /\+\s*\".*\s*\"$/)) ? true : false
```

but this is returning true if `+` operator is used as

```
stringObj.replace("//D+","anystring")
```

How can I put an expression to ignore `+` operator used for regular expressions.

Comment: could you explain a bit further and also show what is the value of textLine?

Comment: textLine is any string line. It might be the whole source code also.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to match `+` except when it is between double quotes. The easiest way to do is to match first what you don't want and make the match fail using verb and then to match what you want.

Something like

```
"(?>[^"\\]|\\.)*"(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|\+
```

Comment: Thanks. You got my motive right but this expression does not work with my language. Compile time error is thrown with comment as Dangling metacharacter. @Nahuel

Comment: alternatively you can ensure the number of double quotes (except escaped ones) is even : `\+(((?>[^"\\]|\\.)*"){2})*+(?>[^"\\]|\\.)*$`

Comment: or depending how regex is used within your code keep the first idea and checking programmaticaly which branch matched, discarding unwanted matches

Comment: I am trying to build a regex to find + operator used exactly within " " but i am not able to. It always matches something like, " " + " ", to true.